# Sharepoint event handler refresh page

Tags: development, event-receivers

I have an event handler that updates an list item on checkedin. However the user doesn't see the updated list until you refresh the page. How would I go about fixing this issue? code in c#
Code as follows

```
 public override void ItemCheckedIn(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {

            base.EventFiringEnabled = false;


            SPFile file = properties.ListItem.File;
            file.CheckOut();
            properties.ListItem["ManualDisposalSet"] = "True";

            listItem.SystemUpdate(false);

            file.CheckIn("Updating Object", SPCheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);
            file.Update();

             base.ItemCheckedIn(properties);
            String url = properties.AfterUrl;


        }
```

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=AJAXRefreshView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is that the `ItemCheckedIn` event is asynchronous, meaning that it will execute after the file has been checked in and the user has been redirected. Instead, if possible in your scenario, try the [`ItemCheckingIn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemcheckingin(v=office.14).aspx) that is synchronous